# Android: Custom view does draw

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, android-view

So I know there are a lot of questions like this, but none of the answers have had any effect.

I have a custom `View` that I am trying to put into a `ScrollView` (all programmatically). The `ScrollView` itself works fine, is where it needs to be, does what it's supposed to do and when tested by adding a `TextView` to it, still did what it was supposed to.

However when I create my custom `View` the view doesn't draw and it is as if nothing is there. The `draw(Canvas canvas)` method is never called (also tried with `onDraw` even though I don't know what the difference is but it still didn't work).

I have tried things such as `setWillNotDraw(false)` in the constructor, called `View.invalidate()` every time I want it to draw/redraw, nothing appears to be working.

Here is the relevant code:

**ScrollView Initialized**

```
sv = new ScrollView(env.getContext());
ScaledBounds sb = UsefulMethods.getScaledBounds(50, 200, BBEnvironment.WIDTH - 100, BBEnvironment.HEIGHT - 300);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(sb.getWidth(), sb.getHeight());
sv.setTranslationX(sb.getX());
sv.setTranslationY(sb.getY());
sv.setLayoutParams(params);
sv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
sv.setScrollBarSize(0);
sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(150, 0, 255, 0));
```

**Custom View Class**

```
private class LevelSelectionView extends View {
    private ArrayList<LevelButton> levelButtons;

    public LevelSelectionView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        levelButtons = new ArrayList<LevelButton>();
        int x = 20;
        int y = 20;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            levelButtons.add(new LevelButton(x, y, 100, 100, 10, i + 1));
            levelButtons.get(i).unlock();
            x += 100 + 20;
        }

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        System.out.println("is being called"); //except it isn't
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(env.getCurrentSettings().getAntialias());

        for(LevelButton lb : levelButtons)
            lb.drawObject(canvas, paint);
    }
}
```

**Creating and adding custom view**

```
LevelSelectionView lsView = new LevelSelectionView(sv.getContext());
lsView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(sv.getLayoutParams().width, 1000));
lsView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(150, 0, 0, 255));
sv.addView(lsView);
```

Why is it not drawing and how do I get it to draw?

Comment: How did you add `view` to ScrollView? Did you tried to set color to paint variable? Does the custom view work separately in xml?

Comment: @emiraslan looks like I cut some code. The `View` is added to the `ScrollView` using `sv.addView(lsView)`   Note: added relevant code

Comment: You should override onDraw(Canvas) instead of draw. Can you please add the code where you create and add the CustomView to the ScrollView.

Comment: @Eselfar I had tried using `onDraw` instead of `draw` but that didn't work either. Code added

Comment: Where do you call the code which creates the CustomView?

Answer (score 0):

I tried like that and it works:

```
public class LevelSelectionView extends View {
    private final static String TAG = LevelSelectionView.class.getSimpleName();

    private final ArrayList<Button> mButtons;
    private final Paint mPaint;

    public LevelSelectionView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        int x = 20;
        int y = 20;

        mPaint = new Paint();
//        mPaint.setAntiAlias(env.getCurrentSettings().getAntialias());


        Button myButton;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            myButton = new Button(context);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


            mButtons.add(myButton);
//            mButtons.get(i).unlock();
//            x += 100 + 20;
        }

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (Button lb : mButtons)
            Log.d(TAG, "is being called"); //except it isn't
//            lb.drawObject(canvas, mPaint);
    }
}
```

I don't know what is your LevelButton as it's a custom class. 
I create the LevelSelectionView like that, using a FrameLayout but it's the same idea with the ScrollView:

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

LevelSelectionView view = new LevelSelectionView(this);
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

container.addView(view);
```

Maybe your issue comes from the LevelButton or the context you use (as you use the Context from env to create the ScrollView and the Context of the ScrollView to create your custom class). You code is not clear as we don't know what is your `env` object as all your class are inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to properly implement `onMeasure` so the scrollview knows how tall that view is.